# Connecting to MYSQL error

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc

My code is wrote in C#
I have a problem while connecting to MYSQL remote DB .
The remote DB is 64 bit while the one in local system is 32bit.
The one in 32bit works, the one in remote doesn't.
Im using this version of drivers : " DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}; ", one in 32bit , the other one in 64bit (remote one)

This is the error i got :

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005):
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified

Anyone has any ideas to deal with this?
Thanks

Comment: Are the 32 bit and 64 bit databases have the same structure, data etc? Based on the error, it is just that the data source name is not found. So it could literally may have been a configuration issue, not a version issue.

Comment: I know that it is not a version issue but whats then the configuration issue?

Comment: The objects in both databases simply may not be identical, or it could be a setting and there is no way for Stackoverflow members to know which setting it would be. There are tons of settings related to the ODBC drivers. The driver may not even have a data source created. Have you checked anything?